# Error --> "Can't logout() while you are in login"

Tags: jquery-terminal

While using jquery terminal, sometimes if without logging in if I try to call logout() it is throwing me an error like "U can't logout while you are in login". Any idea about this..?

Comment: If you terminal is asking for login, you have `login:` or `password:` you just can't run `logout()` so users can't get out from main login. Right now I'm not sure if it was good idea. Maybe breaking from login and breaking from password input should work.

Do you have a demo what show your problem or steps how to reproduce? The code would be helpful.

Comment: Hi jcubic, I will try to share demo soon, and one more problem I'm facing with the login is that, even if the username is blank or not valid, then in that case also its showing only password is incorrect.